# CORS in ASP.NET Core in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cors

I found interesting problem. I deployed my ASP.NET Core REST API on IIS and when I called it, I had this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https...' from origin 'https:...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https:'.
```

but it was working few minutes ago. I checked the response header and this was there:

```
access-control-allow-headers: content-type,odata-maxversion,odata-version
access-control-allow-methods: GET, GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *, *
```

Then I realised I restarted the service. For some reason my code and IIS duplicate HTTP response header values every time the service is uploaded. When I delete HTTP Response Header values in IIS, it works. This is my Startup.cs code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllPolicy", builder =>
      {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
      }));
      services.AddControllers();
      ...
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      app.UseCors("AllPolicy");
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
```

Do you have any ideas why are the header values duplicated everytime when is the service uploaded? And do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: How are you publishing the website to IIS?

Comment: @Vistari Project- Publish - to a folder. target runtime win-x64, deployment mode: Framework-dependent

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the "app.UseCors("AllPolicy");" to right after app.UseRouting();
 so that it looks like:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllPolicy");
```